# How to write codes in different languages in android studio?

Tags: android, android-layout, fonts, localization

I searched internet for three days about this but I didn't get anything. 
I know how to use multiple language in android

```
res
  values-fr
```

I want to use Odia language so need to write odia in android studio.
like :-

```
<Button android:textColor="#ffefefef"android:id="@id/btn_resume"android:background="@drawable/button_shape" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="5dp" android:text="ପୁର୍ବଥର ପଢୁଥିଲେ..."`/>
```

In the above code "ପୁର୍ବଥର ପଢୁଥିଲେ..." this part is written in Odia I want to code like this, but I cant understand how to write another language, I also tried to write somewhere else and copy that text and paste in android studio but android not compiling the text. So I am in horrible condition. Please someone help me.
Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

write like this:

```
<Button 
     android:textColor="#ffefefef"
     android:id="@id/btn_resume"
     android:background="@drawable/button_shape" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_margin="5dp" 
     android:text="@string/Button_text"/>
```

1. for en:

> res/values-en/String.xml
>
> `<string name="Button_text">Your_text_in_en</string>`

2. for your Odia:

> res/velues-YOUR_LANG/String.xml
>
> `<string name="Button_text">Your_text_in_Your_1st_lan</string>`

......
X. for other:

> res/velues-other_LANG/String.xml
>
> `<string name="Button_text">Your_text_in_Your_other_lan</string>`